# Finding the curve of intersection of a cylinder and cone

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I have a cone $x^2 + y^2 -z^2 =0$ and a cylinder $ x^2 +y^2 -2ax =0$. Together they look like this.

[image: 3D Plot of quadrics using geogebra]

If one were to project the intersection onto the xy plane, the curve given by this intersection would be an ellipse.

To attain the equation for this ellipse I have attempted to solve the equations of these quadrics simultaneosly when $z=0$ but this has been leading me nowhere.

Any suggestions?

The context for this work is to find the surface area of the cone inside the cylinder. To do this I consider a surface integral whose region will be defined by this intersection curve.

Comment: The projection of the curve onto the $x$-$y$ plane isn’t just any old ellipse: it’s a circle. Setting $z=0$ isn’t the right approach—you’re then trying to compute the intersection of _three_ surfaces, which in this case consists only of the origin.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but just ran across it today.

The projection lies on the cylinder and on the plane $z=0$. Therefore it must be the circle with equation $x^2 +y^2 -2ax=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: You need to start by parametrizing your cone. I suggest you work just with half of it, say $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Presumably polar coordinates would be the best coordinates to use for this. Now find *in those coordinates* where the region you're interested in stops, i.e., the intersection with the cylinder. (The circle $x^2+y^2-2ax=0$ in the $xy$-plane has a very nice equation in polar coordinates.)